# Xcode failed with exit code 254

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault, swift, xcode6

I've looked for a solution but i found nothing. Withe the beta 3 of XCode 6 my code doesn't work anymore. Xcode returns me this error:

> While emitting SIL for 'tableView' at
>   /Users/Marco/Desktop/iPrescription/iPrescription/MedicineTableViewController.swift:109:14
>   :0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11 
>   :0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use
>   -v to see invocation) Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   failed with exit code 254

i'm new to ios programming and i don't know what to do to finding the origin of this problem. I'm very frustrated because i don't know what looking for.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the swift compiler.  You should go back to beta 2.

Comment: Actual code would be helpful. It looks like a compiler bug, but there might be a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same issue for me, but with collection view in my case. I found it caused by line:

```
let cell = collectionView?.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCell
```

I just changed it to:

```
let cell = collectionView!.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCell
```

and my app back to life again. Still have no idea why.

UPDATE:

Just noticed that method signature changed in beta3 and collectionView (to tableView in your case) forced to unwrap:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView**!**, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell!
```

so we need to fix data source methods and use collectionView or tableView directly.